# How can I reference 2 different SQLServer assemblies to call SSIS from .net (4.5)

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, reference, ssis

I have a web app that calls SSIS packages built in 2008. As we migrate to VS2013 and SQL2014 I've started upgrading my SSIS packages using 2013.

I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32093712/referencing-multiple-versions-of-the-same-assembly) (that I don't have enough rep to comment on) that talks about multiple assembly references, but I'm not sure where the code goes, as my Web.config file doesn't even have the current Microsoft.SQLServer.ManagedDTS that I added 
(right click, add reference, browse to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\SDK\Assemblies\Microsoft.SQLServer.ManagedDTS.dll)

So, I'm wondering if the 12.0.0.0 version could be used to call dts packages created in '08 AND the dtsx packages created in '10? (with special parameters?)

Or, how do I have both referenced? (obviously if I try to have both VS says you can't have both, one already exists.) I'm looking at the reference paths section under the Project Properties, but it's empty ...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try using entity Framework to add two  connection strings with different datacontexts of each assembly reference in the web.config file.

Comment: not sure how to do that -- my web.config file has no reference to any sql dll. can you give me an example?