# Referencing multiple versions of the same assembly in .NET Core?

Tags: .net, .net-core

There is same question for .NET Framework: [Referencing multiple versions of the same assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32093712/referencing-multiple-versions-of-the-same-assembly)

How to achieve the same in .NET Core 3?

Comment: It depends how you reference them, but see here for an example with NuGets and direct DLL: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49307481/supporting-multiple-versions-of-nuget-package-in-one-library-nuget-package

Comment: @boast I need to resolve conflict between libraries, some from NuGet are using current version of `Newtonsoft.Json` and one old is direct dll that is using old version of `Newtonsoft.Json` also as direct dll. It is not my code, that is using `Newtonsoft.Json`.

Comment: The problem is, if the referenced package(s) leak the dependency (e.g. not setting `<PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>` on the `PackageReference` entry) you cannot do much AFAIK.

Comment: Could I somehow modify the DLL with old dependency to force using it's particular version it's dependency. And not to use the new version? (E.g. to modify somehow the old DLL with ILSpy.)